# Navigating the file system with netbeans is VERY slow

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

Since a few days, navigating the file system with Netbeans is VERY slow (more than two minutes to access a file, and if you have to navigate a file system, it is true every time. I have exactly the same problem after clearing the cache, and with Netbeans 8.2 and Netbeans 12 (Netbeans 8 with Java 8, and Netbeans 12 with Java 17 in my tests).

Strangely I don't have the same problem with regular Java file choosers which I use in my projects. For example, if I click on "Open Project", the IDE is frozen for sometimes 2 or 3 minutes before I can see the file navigator.

When I am looking in the task manager while trying to open a project for example, it appear that Network usage is very low (1% to 0%), CPU also very low (less than 2%)

I am talking about Netbeans itself, for example if I want to open an existing project, or adding a jar file to the list of Jar libraries for an existing project

The standard Swing JFileChooser works correctly. With this example code the navigation is immediate (as expected):

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();            
chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG);         
chooser.setDialogTitle("Test FileChooser");  
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);         
int ret = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);         
if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION{ 
   System.out.println(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());        
}
```

I am on Windows, on my workplace network (I am working on local files on my PC, but there are two remote drives which are accessible on the network). I only have problems with Netbeans, other apps have no problem with the file system.

My problem is with Netbeans itself navigating the file system (for example opening an existing project, or adding a jar file as a library for a project)

This looks to behave exactly as this bug: https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=42079, except that it does not happen with the Swing `JFileChooser` as shown above.

Is it a known problem, and if it is, is there a mean to fix it? I was thinking for example about a setting on the command line used to start Netbeans.

Comment: `Strangely I don't have the same problem with regular Java file choosers which I use in my projects.` Well, what file chooser are you using that creates this specific problem or are you talking about NetBeans itself? Maybe it needs more permissions to access the file system on the network.

Comment: I updated the question as of your proposal :)

Comment: Some basic things to check while the file navigation is slow: [1] In Windows Task Manager verify that there is no abnormal use of memory, CPU or I/O. [2] Verify that there is plenty of free space on your hard drives, especially the C: drive. [3] Use the Windows Event Viewer app to check the System and Application Event logs for unusual errors/activity. [4] Review the NetBeans log file (View > IDE Log) for errors and stack traces. [5] In NetBeans go to the Services panel, select Maven Repositories > Local, right click and select Update Index from the context menu. Does it complete quickly?

Comment: Also: [1] The fact that you are having problems on releases 8.2 and 12 of NetBeans suggests that this might be an environment issue rather than a NetBeans problem. [2] No release of NetBeans 12 supports Java 12! Instead, all NetBeans 12.x releases support the LTS versions JDK 8 and JDK 11, plus whatever JDK is current when NetBeans 12.x is released. [3] Which specific version of NetBeans 12 are you running? If it is 12.0 then you should use JDK 11 or JDK 14 rather than JDK 12.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo I didn't see, I'm using JDK 17.0.1 with Netbeans 12.0. Should I try JDK 14 instead for my tests?

Comment: Update index is immediate for Maven

Comment: But I'm not able to see anything concerning Netbeans in the event viewer, I will look closer this afternoon.

Comment: The same behavior for NetBeans 12.4 and 12.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the guilty one was my enterprise AntiVirus (Trend Micro Apex).

Unloading it, ended the slowness immediately.

For the record I was Using Netbeans 19 with the JVM 17.08 on Windows 11.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue on Windows, thanks to you guys I solved it by removing the symbolic links (shortcuts) from the desktop, **but not from any desktop**, I mean that this method didn't work for me when I removed them from the user desktop "**C:\Users\user\Desktop**", it only worked when I removed them from the public desktop, which is located at "**C:\Users\Public\Desktop**".

*I hope this clarification helps and sorry I don't have enough reputation here on StackOverflow to comment, so I had to post this as an answer....*

Answer (score 3):

It was a BROKEN PATH in a link on the desktop in Windows 10, in my case.

NetBeans 12.5 -> Creating a new project dialog, than "Browse" to choose appropriate directory took a very long time. I tried to test links on my desktop. I found one old "broken link". Broken in terms - it pointed out to non existent path. I corrected this path in this link and... voilà, magically NetBeans is working correctly.

Comment: I had the same issue . I moved all files from the desktop to another folder to check and Netbeans (Netbeans 18) started to working fine. Reference
https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/4673#issuecomment-1255106193

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in netbeans with links from the desktop, that behaves like you described. Try to remove all links from the desktop and default location for the open file dialog.

[issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-1537](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-1537)

Comment: Thanks!! I will do that!!

Comment: Tried. Don't see a difference. Don't know where to set "default location for the open file dialog"

Answer (score 2):

Ok -- this is crazy -- but after trying everything listed, here is what finally worked for me.
I created a Batch file on the desktop to point to the netbeans64.exe app.  the secret for me was to *NOT* do a cd to the netbeans location.. but to call the app in using the full path. Here is what my batch file looks like

"C:\Program Files\NetBeans-15\netbeans\bin\netbeans64.exe"

I know it seems way too easy.. but it works for me.  As Sam Snead said about the latest golf gear back in the 60's  "I ain't no scientist. just a believer.." LOL!!!

Comment: impressive!!! And you are right, so strange!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. As they wrote here, it is necessary to check the links on the desktop. Removing bad links helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue with Netbeans 15. Resolved it by removing a broken shortcut from my desktop.

Comment: please modify or remove your answer. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I find that this happens when I run Netbeans without administrator rights.
With admin rights it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the solution here:
https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/6800

Adding this option in the netbeans.conf to netbeans_default_options:
-J-Dnb.FileChooser.useShellFolder=false